# Count multiple Data in a string cell

Tags: r

I would count with the func table() in R how many time a value occures in a cell. But, some cell contains more value divided by colon. I report an example below:

```
example <- data.frame(c("A","B","A:::B"))
table(example)
```

the result is:

```
A A:::B     B 
1     1     1
```

but i want something like this

```
A     B 
2     2
```

I try to duplicate the rows with this characteristics, but the dataset is already too large and duplicate rows makes dataset impossible to use. How can i do?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can split the column values by `:::` and get the `table`

```
table(unlist(strsplit(example[[1]], "\\:+")))
#  A B 
#  2 2
```